# Creatin a working copy with svn and ftp

Tags: svn

I have an issue with workingcopy with svn,so I installed my svn repository on my remote server(ovh mutualisé pro),then I checkout the project to my local machine.

the url of svn is :

```
svn+ssh://ftp.domain.com/homez.xxx/login/svn/trunk/project
```

I checkout my project locally in :

/var/www/

Now I make changes on my local machine and commit to svn and until now is good,my issue is to create a working copy in another folder on my remote server to see changes on line on browser and the url is :

```
login@ftp.domain.com/www
```

So I tried to use `svn export` like that :

```
svn export svn+ssh://ftp.domain.com/homez.xxx/login/svn/trunk login@ftp.domain.com/www
```

it's demand from me the ftp password after I enter my password(is correct),i get this error :

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I spend myabe two days but until now I don't know how to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do this. A working copy must be put on a local filesystem (or something that looks like one).

If you want an update to your website after you commit, see [the FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update)

Answer (score -1):

I will answer my self :), so I found a partial solution to my problem then,I access to my remote server inside folder of live server and I checkout my repo like that :

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://ftp.domain.com/homez.xxx/login/svn/trunk .
```

so I can see all changes with my browser,but I have another small issue that when I use `svn update` to retrieve all modifications,I get this error :

```
Skipped 'svn+ssh://ftp...
```